# Execute Inline JavaScript code within IFrame src attribut

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Is it possible to execute inline JavaScript code on src attribute of an existing IFrame (function that do some logic and return an url ) ?

When I try the code, I get the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var hello = function(src1){
            // some logic goes here
   return "www.mysite.com";
  } 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <iframe width="400" height="400" src="javascript:hello()"   > 
 </iframe>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to set the src attribute a different way.

Comment: I know It is possible to fetch the iframe HTMLElement and set its src dynamically. I was looking for minimal way to fo the same task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put inline javascript in src attribute. You can use onload event for this. Use the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hello = function(src1){
            // some logic goes here
            return "mysitename.com";
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe width="400" height="400" onload="this.src = hello()">   
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I need, i need the hello to block the loading of the iframe ( blank content) until the function hello returns some result ( external ajax call ). is there ondomcontentloaded listener for iframes ?

Comment: If you want to insert url after the ajax call than in the response result of ajax just insert document.getElementById("iframeid").src = "YOUR URL". It should work fine

Comment: this causes an infinite loop, i think when the iframe loads it change its src and reload again , triggers onload infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

The call to hello() is is executing inside the iframe ( because 'javascript:hello()' is the iframe SRC)
But the function 'hello()' is declared outside the iframe in the parent window, in which the iframe is embedded. 
You can either call parent.hello() in your iframe src, or declare the body of hello() in the iframe src before calling hello(). The following demonstrates both methods :

```
<script>
    var hello = function(){
        alert('hello from outside the iframe');
    }
</script>

<iframe width="400" height="400" src="javascript:var hello = function(){alert('hello from inside the iframe')};hello();parent.hello()"></iframe>
```

You can see it in action here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/vtdc1qxf/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.write`.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<iframe width="400" height="400" src="' + hello() + '"></iframe>')
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Though, I think the solution that @Hudixt posted is probably better.  Just providing an alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, i dont have much control over iframes, iframes are already present on the page, i can only add attributes (which is the maximum change i can do).

Comment: @user3075416 Could you please add that to the original question for future people to see if they stumble upon your question?